# Using stack and file read to balance out C Style code in python

Tags: python

I think I managed to get it working with a stack, not sure. But I need to balance out C-style code that is within a text file. I don't know if I made the stack bit correct.

```
class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self._items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self._items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self._items)

open_list = ["[","{","("]
close_list = ["]","}",")"]
count = 0
stack = []
fileOpen = input("Please enter the name of the file with C style code - should end in .txt ")
my_file = open(fileOpen + ".txt","r")
the_record = my_file.readlines()
count = count + 1
for i in the_record:
    the_record = the_record[:-1]
    if i in open_list:
        stack.append(i)
    elif i in close_list:
        pos = close_list.index(i)
        if ((len(stack) > 0) and
            (open_list[pos] == stack[len(stack)-1])):
            stack.pop()
        else:
            print("Line", count, "is Not OK wrt bracket matching")
if len(stack) == 0: 
    print("Line", count, "is OK")
```

In the text file

```
asdasdas([])
adas[](
```

I expected to show all the results like:

```
Line 1 is Ok
Line 2 is Not Ok
```

Instead only line 1 appears:

```
Line 1 is Ok
```

Answer (score 0):

The `the_record` variable is a list of **lines**. So `i` is always *a line* and neither `asdasdas([])` nor `adas[](` belong to `open_list` nor `close_list` hence the `for` loop does nothing. When it exits no element was *ever* added to `stack` hence `len(stack) == 0` and `Line 1 is OK` is printed.

```
the_record = my_file.readlines()
# --> the_record == ['asdasdas([])\n', 'adas[]('] <--

for i in the_record:
    # i == 'asdasdas([])\n`

    the_record = the_record[:-1]
    if i in open_list:  # False: 'asdasdas([])\n' is not contained in ["(","[","{"]
        # never executed, condition always false
        stack.append(i)
    elif i in close_list: # False: 'asdasdas([])\n' is not contained in [")","]","}"]

        # never executed condition always false

if len(stack) == 0: # True: stack is [] because you never added anything to it.
    print("Line", count, "is OK")
```

You need a double for loop, once over the lines and one over the characters of a single line:

```
with open(fileOpen + ".txt","r") as infile:
    for index, line in enumerate(infile, start=1):
        stack = []
        for char in line:
            if char in open_list:
                stack.append(char)
            elif char in close_list:
                # ...
        if not stack:
            print('Line', index, 'is OK')
```